# vba/Office: How to get the server name as a string from an "Application" object?

Tags: vba, object, office-interop

Is there a way to get the server name as a string from an "Application" object using vba?

An example of code is:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim SrvrName As String
    SrvrName = Application.ServerName 'Pseudocode
End Sub
```

An example of output is: "Excel.Application", "Outlook.Application", "Word.Application", etc.

I have need to pass this string to an external vbscript file. This string must change dynamically depending on the application in use.

Comment: Please, do not post images of code.  Instead post the actual code, formatted as code

Comment: done...........

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after the `TypeName()` function.

```
Sub test()
Dim oExcelApp as Variant
Set oExcelApp = Application
MsgBox TypeName( oExcelApp ) 'Outputs: "Application"
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not what I want, I want it to exactly return the string entered in the "Class" parameter of the "GetObject" function, ie "Excel.Application".

Comment: "Application" is the class. "Excel" is the library. Any reason for not just storing the string?

Comment: Yes, because i have to pass this string to an external vbscript file. This string must change dynamically depending of the application I use

Comment: Not sure what the use case is here. In any case - there's no quick fix to return what you're after in VBA or vbscript itself that I'm aware of. You can check for running Applications etc. but that's not "returning the class name" as you asked